# How to prevent space and hyphen change line and make line break with specific width?

Tags: css

How to prevent space and hyphen change line and make line break withspecific width ?

I know if I change the dash to `&#8209` and space `&nbsp` it works. but is there any other way to do it without change the content from db.

I also tried `white-space:no-wrap;` but the text will not break line with the specific width .

http://jsfiddle.net/eD4Ht/

```
<div>textfromdb-textfromdbtextfromdbtextfromdb- textfromdbtextfromdbtextfromdb textfromdb</div>
div{
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: 1.line break with width  2.hyphen and space not change line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want the string in the `div` element to be rendered within the given width so that line breaks are entered *only* when the width limit is reached. For this purpose, `word-wrap: break-word` is not suitable, as it just allows browsers to break “words” arbitrarily *when normal wrapping is not enough*. You wish to *replace* normal wrapping by simple, mechanical fitting. For this, use [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) instead:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```